# How to delete an album in the Photos app?

Tags: macos, applications, photos, photos.app

How do I delete unwanted albums in the Mac Photos app?

Answer (score 2):

Select the Album, hit the Delete / Backspace <kbd>⌫</kbd> Key, or right / control click on it and select "Delete Album"; click on the "Delete" button that appears on the confirmation dialog at the top of the app (Are you sure you want to delete this album?).

Answer (score 0):

I find a same post in this forum and the answer to your question, you can check it.
[Delete album from Photos.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189511/delete-album-from-photos-app)