# How to quickly delete multiple albums in Photos app (OS X)

Tags: photos.app, macos, album

My Photos app (on OS X) has very many (well over a hundred) albums sitting inside an iPhoto Events folder. Most of the albums have are named by a day, e.g. '16 May 2014'. In order to delete an album I need to right click, select delete album and then say YES, when I'm asked when I'm sure. To clean up all these old (and unwanted) albums is taking ages.

Is there a quicker way of deleting albums? The keyboard shortcut mentioned in this [Ask Different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197604/how-to-delete-an-album-in-the-photos-app) (hitting delete with the album selected) does not work for me. I can only do the right click thing. Adding a keyboard shortcut with the contextual (right click) menu didn't work either. I can't select multiple albums at once and delete them all either.

Am I missing a trick, or is the app just designed to make deleting albums a one at a time and confirm every time thing?

### Update

Some more experimentation and, in line with @dankohn below, it is possible to do this. Things to note:

1. You can't select multiple albums in the Sidebar. So if you want to select multiple albums to delete you need to do it in the main window. *This confused me* - so maybe it will have confused others too.
2. Selecting **Album view** (or using ⌘ 3) does not necessarily take you into a view of Albums. If you've previously been looking *inside* an album, selecting this view changes the main window to show the *photos inside that album*, i.e. you don't get to see the list of albums at all. If this happens, you need use the back button (top left) to go back to the listing of Albums. *This confused me* - so maybe it will have confused others too.

Once you have got a list of albums showing the main window, as @dankohn, you can select multiple albums (using Shift Click or ⌘ Click) and then you can delete them using a Right Click / the contextual menu.

Note: All this applies to Photos 1.0.1 running on Yosemite. Things may have changed with El Capitan.

Comment: Thanks for documenting this. Apple's UIs aren't often as intuitive as they're reputed to be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select View: Albums. Click the first album, than shift click the last album. Then right-click any of the selected albums and select Delete, to delete them all.

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to do this in the Sidebar, where it does not work. Once I tried with the Albums showing in the main window, then it did work. (I've updated my question for anyone else who might get confused in the same way.) Puzzling it doesn't work in the sidebar, but there you go... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY IT WORKED!
This finally worked with your suggestion of Not using the sidebar but clicking at the top of it where it says'albums'. They then all show up on a screen and you can delete just like you delete on regular photos.